# Social Login - Google login button missing (Adifier) Can't find PHP file relating to page

Tags: google, wordpress, looking-for-a-script, social-media

Using the Adifier plugin I have set it up so users can login with Facebook and Google.

Facebook Login working, but for some reason no button shows up for Google.

I cannot find the PHP page relating to this. 
I tried searching inside & outside the plugin directory using windows search (File Contents) for an HTML tag but cannot find any.

The database does not contain the tag either.

Picture showing where 'Google Login' should be. Note: there is no element here. Nor any CSS hiding the element.

[image: Google login missing]

Comment: [Adifier](https://themeforest.net/item/adifier-classified-ads-wordpress-theme/21633950) looks like a WordPress plugin that is only available for a fee and which has limited or no documentation available online.   Rather than ask here, it would probably be better to contact their customer support.   I doubt that anybody here would have used it before and nobody is going to pay $49 to experiment with it to answer your question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for the reply. Tbh I didn't know it costed anything, I'm just trying to update a website for a customer. I've contacted the support there too